# xlink:href not working in firefox

Tags: svg, xlink

I'm using  xlink:href to display the svg, it's working in both safari and chrome. But not in firefox, any idea?:

```
<div class="cart-badge">
 <span class="icon">
  <svg>
   <use xlink:href="#shape-cart"></use>
  </svg>
 </span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE :**

I have the base set here in index

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var baseDom = document.createElement('base');

var headDom = document.querySelector('head');

baseDom.setAttribute('href','/');

if(document.querySelector('base')===null)
{
    headDom.appendChild(baseDom);
}
</script>
```

svg not working in firefox.

I then  add `$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});` in the `.config` and totally remove the base, svg is showing, the problem now is that it wont call my api without the base.

Comment: Have you got a `<base>` tag in your actual code because xlink:href does work in Firefox.

Comment: The code in the question should demonstrate the issue. This doesn't. The xlink:href doesn't point to anything.

Comment: @RobertLongson question edited :)

Comment: The value of the base tag prepends to the href (as it should). Use an absolute URI if you want to use a `<base>` tag. Chrome/Safari should do this but don't.

Answer (score -1):

Use direct svg i.e the path not the

`<use xlink:href=""></use>`